# Invalid conversion from char to 'uint8_t'

Tags: arduino

I'm using a shift out statement to drive a few 7 seg displays (in the end)
but I'm running into a problem.

I have used `#include <avr/pgmspace.h>` libary as to save space for the processing.
At the end of it I need to shiftOut a binary number to be fed into a reg then to a BCD then to my display:

```
strcpy_P(buffer, (char*)pgm_read_word(&(Times[big])));

shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, MSBFIRST, buffer);
```

in the buffer place will go the selected value (e.g. B00100011 should display 23),
my code gives me

```
Invalid conversion from char to 'uint8_t'
```

with the shiftOut line highlighted

Any ideas?

Comment: What are the types of all your variables?  And what is the declaration of `shiftOut`?

Comment: Try compiling as C instead of C++.

Comment: I am doing this in the Arduino enviroment so it is a mix of both C and C++

Comment: oh and the big variable is an int and the buffer is a char array that I have made sure that is is big enough to fit the whole char that needs to be sent as for the declaration of shiftOut I have no clue what you are talking about ,,, sorry

Comment: Are you sure that B00100011 should give you 23? I think it's 35 in binary.

Comment: It would be useful to see the declaration of `Times` and `big` as that is likely the source of the problem.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth `shiftOut` is a standard arduino function, defined here: http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/shiftOut

Comment: As for B00100011 the way I have been working on this is that each 4 binary digits is a separate number IE so B ( tells shiftOut there is a binary number coming ,, 0010 = 2 and 0011 = 3 ... But the first answer got me to a working code :) Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that [`shiftOut`](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/shiftOut) expects a byte (`uint8_t`) as its 4th argument (`value`). The passed value is a `char*` (presumably declared as a `prog_char` array).

To fix this, the declaration of the value will need to use `prog_uchar`, like this:

```
prog_uchar values[] PROGMEM = { (prog_uchar) B00100011, ... };

...

int valueIndex = ...; // Index of value in the values array
shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, MSBFIRST, pgm_read_byte(&(values[valueIndex])));
```

Comment: Well I got it to work ,,,, sort of I have not completed the code yet but there are no errors in this section of the code thanks to your help ,,, If I may ask one more question though ,,, I had to change your code a little taking out the B in each of my prog_uchar values[] PROGMEM = { ,,,, }; entries and now I need to find a different way to get it across to the Shiftout function that I'm trying to get binary shifted out not a number ,,, any ideas ?

Comment: You may be able to cast the B001... to a prog_uchar (updated above). If you post your new code as a gist (on https://gist.github.com/) and I'll take a look.

Comment: I have put the file code in that gist website here is the URL I think https://gist.github.com/d7dae9c939d04568aaff

Comment: thanks for all the help so far ,,, need this to work as the only other way I can see of this working a a lot more code and a few hundred if statements :( thanks again

Comment: Please forgive me for being slow, but I've looked at the code and I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do... Could you provide some example temperature readings (float values which could be returned from `recordings()` and the respective binary value you want to `shiftOut()`. From the code you posted it looks like you'll read past the `values` array if the temperature is over 99 degrees. Also you have the value `00010001` (11) twice in the array and seem to be missing `00010000` (10).

Comment: The problem you were having with the B prefix was that the first couple of numbers had 9 bits. I've updated your gist (https://gist.github.com/d529bce3f3475d6262e1) with the right values and added some temporary code to print out the values in a readable form. I'm still not sure how this is supposed to work (the fractional part of the temperature - `small` - is not used at all, is this correct?) but it does at least store and retrieve the values I think you want.

Comment: thanks :) changed those problems and I have a working code now sorry for the problem with getting the info across found out that the temp I need to read is only between 0 and 40 so I 'm going with some IF statements to make things easier :) sticking with what I now for this bit ,,, thanks again been a big help with getting to understand PROGMEM functions :)